# How to take input via console in javascript (node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console

I am facing difficulties taking input in Javascript. I use nodejs to run js files using the following command:

```
node filename.js
```

Can someone tell me all the ways in which I can input a 2D matrix from the console?

Also, why is it so difficult in JS? 
I am looking for a simple method like gets() or something equivalent of cin in C++.

Comment: What format would your 2D matrix be? A string that you enter from the console? You can pass arguments to Node via `var myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);`. Then something like `node filename.js argument1 argument2` would make `myArgs` equal to `["argument1", "argument2"]` https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/command-line/how-to-parse-command-line-arguments/

Comment: This may help you.[Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html)

Comment: Actually I want to take input after I've run node filename.js.

Comment: @EmptyBrain I've used this method also. I want to know how to take input in global variables. If I take input in a variable using the Readline method, the value of the variable does not exist outside rl.question{} scope.

Comment: @NamanBansal [this solution might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28023320/4849143)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`process.stdin`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) which read data from your standard input as a stream, which is roughly equivalent to C++ `cin`.

```
process.stdin.on('readable', () => {
  let data;
  while ((data = process.stdin.read()) !== null) {
    try {
      let obj = JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(obj[1][0])  // -> 3
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Not a 2D Matrix')
      continue;
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
node index.js
foo
Not a 2D Matrix
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
3
```